# Python List Sum If Double Counting

Tags: python, list, sum, duplicates

I am unable to troubleshoot the below error. Key values are at the top. When using in a SUMIF fashion to total the daily counts using the index reference, if a value is shared *(apples and peaches are both 2)* the sum function at the bottom creates duplicate counts within both items' conditional sums. If the values are all unique *(i.e. apples = 2 and peaches = 3)*, this does not occur.

What do I need to do to resolve this duplicate sum with condition issue?

```
# FOOD COST
apples = 2
peaches = 2
nectarines = 4
mangoes = 5
bananas = 7

"""
IF THE SAME VALUE IS SHARED ABOVE, SUM COUNT INCLUDES DUPLICATES
"""

diet = [
    # DATE, FOOD, PAID, COUNT
     ['4/1', nectarines, 'y', 1]
    ,['4/5', apples, 'y', 1]
    ,['4/6', peaches, 'y', 1]
    ,['4/8', bananas, 'y', 1]
    ,['4/10', nectarines, 'y', 1]
    ,['4/12', apples, 'y', 1]
    ,['4/12', bananas, 'y', 1]
    ,['4/13', peaches, 'y', 1]
    ,['4/15', nectarines, 'y', 1]
    ,['4/17', apples, 'y', 2]
    ,['4/17', nectarines, 'y', 1]
    ,['4/17', peaches, 'y', 1]
    ,['4/19', apples, 'y', 1]
    ,['4/19', bananas, 'y', 1]
    ,['4/20', peaches, 'y', 1]
    ,['4/22', nectarines, 'y', 1]
    ,['4/22', mangoes, 'y', 1]
    ,['4/24', apples, 'y', 2]
    ,['4/24', peaches, 'y', 1]
    ,['4/24', nectarines, 'y', 1]
    ,['4/26', apples, 'y', 1]
    ,['4/26', bananas, 'y', 1]
    ,['4/27', nectarines, 'y', 1]
]

pome = sum(i[3] for i in diet if i[1] in {apples})
stone = sum(i[3] for i in diet if i[1] in {nectarines,peaches})
tropical = sum(i[3] for i in diet if i[1] in {bananas,mangoes})

print(f'\n{pome} pome fruits')
print(f'{stone} citrus fruits')
print(f'{tropical} tropical fruits\n')

print(f'{sum(i[3] for i in diet)} total diet\n')
```

Comment: what is the result you are getting and what is the expected result? include what are your printing statements giving

Comment: So do you not want: `apples = 2 and peaches = 3`? Why not? It seems useful to give them separate numbers.

Comment: Edit the question to explain more clearly what happens, what should happen.

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't use that SQL leading comma style in Python (or almost everything else that isn't SQL). It exists because SQL throws a fit if you have an excess comma at the end of your last list entry. Python doesn't have this problem, because a single trialling comma is simply ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the food cost as a unique identifier, because the food costs aren't unique!  I'd suggest using an Enum to identify the unique foods, and then have a `food_costs` dict to map each unique `Food` to a possibly non-unique cost:

```
from enum import Enum, auto

class Food(Enum):
    apples = auto()
    peaches = auto()
    nectarines = auto()
    mangoes = auto()
    bananas = auto()

food_costs = {
    Food.apples: 2,
    Food.peaches: 2,
    Food.nectarines: 4,
    Food.mangoes: 5,
    Food.bananas: 7,
}

diet = [
    # DATE, FOOD, PAID, COUNT
    ['4/1', Food.nectarines, 'y', 1],
    ['4/5', Food.apples, 'y', 1],
    # etc
]

def sum_count(*foods):
    return sum(count for _, food, _, count in diet if food in foods)

print()
print(f'{sum_count(Food.apples)} pome fruits')
print(f'{sum_count(Food.nectarines, Food.peaches)} stone fruits')
print(f'{sum_count(Food.bananas, Food.mangoes)} tropical fruits')
print()
print(f'{sum_count(*Food)} total diet')
```

If you wanted to do something like sum the "cost" of the foods the same way that you sum the "count", you'd use the `food_costs` dict to turn a `Food` value into its corresponding cost, e.g.:

```
def sum_cost(*foods):
    return sum(food_costs[food] for _, food, _, _ in diet if food in foods)
```